# Add new option to jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to add your own option to jQgrid,

I would like to add an option lazyLoad

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'example.php',
    // my option
      lazyload: false,
```

Comment: you have to extend plugin to allow your customized options. I don't know specifivally enough this plugin but you should be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks I did it in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by extending the plugin

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults,
    {lazyLoad : false});
```